# Catch multiple onkeyup events from same text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onkeyup

I'm creating some logic for dom scripting and end up finding the problem where I needed to execute multiple methods when pressing a key. It seems the last `onkeyup` defined is the one which executes, here's some code:

**First method:**

```
...var elements=$$('[id^='+table+']&[id$='+tableField+']');

elements.each(function filter(item) {
    
    //for each item 
    item.onkeyup = function() { ...
```

**Second method:**

```
...//for each referenced input    
for(var i=0, fields=htmlFieldElems.length;i<fields;i++){

   //set keyup event for involved fiels in the expression
   $(htmlFieldElems[i]).onkeyup = function() {...
```

It might happen that the input element might be the same in both methods and both need to execute when something changes... so what's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in pure javascript, you can just call multiple methods from your onkeyup event handler, like this ...

```
item.onkeyup = function() {
    func1();
    func2();
    funcn();
}
```

if you are using a framework such as jQuery, you can just keep adding events, like this:

```
$('#item').keyup(func1);
$('#item').keyup(func2);
$('#item').keyup(funcn);
```

Prototype:

```
$('foo').observe('keyup', function(event) {
    func1();
    func2();
    funcn();
});
```

Comment: I've never used prototype, but a quick google suggests the following:

$('foo').observe('keyup', function(event) {
  func1();
  func2();
  funcn();
});

Comment: $('foo').observe('keyup', function(event) {
    func1();
});

$('foo').observe('keyup', function(event) {
    func2();
    funcn();
});

Would this execute the 3 functions?

Comment: yeah! why don't you try it. best way to learn from experimenting!

Comment: yep seems using the observe it will add the method to the event so you can call the observe with the keyup event multiple times.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is what I follow using jQuery. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/HyMPY/)

```
$('#element').bind('customE',function(){
   // do some stuff
});

$('#element').bind('customE',function(){
   // do some other interesting stuff else use one event handler :-)
});

$('#element').bind('customE',function(){
   // still another
});

$('#element').on('keyup',function(){
    $('#element').trigger('customE');   
});
```

Hope this helps.. even other answer posted would help.. But this will be easy to maintain :-)